# HQL Criteria from SQL Case ... when ... then ... end

Tags: hibernate, hql, nhibernate-hql

I want to convert this below SQL query to HQL Criteria but I know how to add simple restriction in HQL Criteria but in this SQL Query has `case`, `when`, `then`, `end`, which I am not familiar to convert into HQL Criteria, so please someone help me to write HQL Criteria with adding restrictions

```
UPDATE Users            
    SET Users.DepartmentalRoleID = TblUser.DepartmentalRoleId, Users.DefaultModuleID = TblUser.ModuleId, Users.DefaultNetworkNo = TblUser.NetworkNo,      
    Users.Department = TblUser.Department, Users.Person_Type = TblUser.PersonType, Users.Email1 = TblUser.Email1, Users.Phone = TblUser.Phone,      
    Users.Fax = TblUser.Fax,      
    Users.DateofDeactivation = CASE WHEN YEAR(TblUser.DateofDeactivation)=1900 THEN NULL ELSE   TblUser.DateofDeactivation END,
    Users.UserUpdated = @UserId, Users.DateUpdated = @DateModified   
    FROM @TblUpdatedUser TblUser      
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users Users ON TblUser.UserIdNo = Users.UserIdNo
```

Comment: You cannot update with criteria.

Comment: You can rewrite your query in HQL query without criteria. Pay attention UPDATE ... FROM is used only in Sql Server. If you use ORM, maybe you want to write a query cross DBMS

Comment: @stefan Steineger: Then will it possible to write Criteria for Insert

Comment: @Thiru: Criteria are used for querying your db. For update and insert use an HQL query

Comment: @JoeTaras: ... or use the ORM as an ORM, say receive objects and update them with OOD technologies.

Comment: Thanks Anyone Please give some example with HQL Select Clause with different tables,joins involved with HQL Criteria API